# Android soap webservice Timeout expired

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

calling soap webservice using below code:

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    AppLog.logString(TAG+"Property info");
    PropertyInfo proInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    proInfo.setName("strInputData");
    proInfo.setValue(jsonValue);
    proInfo.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(proInfo);

    AppLog.logString(TAG+"envelope");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    AppLog.logString(TAG+"HttpTransportSE");
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL, 30000);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"call");
        androidHttpTransport.call(Constants.NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"call1");
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"Responce: "+response.toString());
        result=response.toString();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Mostly getting timeout exception when calling soap webservice

```
01-06 17:41:50.722: W/System.err(11832): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41482960
01-06 17:41:50.722: W/System.err(11832):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:214)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at com.accusol.accuerp.utility.Utility.setDataFromWebServiceSOAP(Utility.java:189)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at com.accusol.accuerp.ui.MyCustomerDetailViewActivity$FragmentOrder$HttpAsyncTaskPOST.doInBackground(MyCustomerDetailViewActivity.java:359)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at com.accusol.accuerp.ui.MyCustomerDetailViewActivity$FragmentOrder$HttpAsyncTaskPOST.doInBackground(MyCustomerDetailViewActivity.java:1)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-06 17:41:50.730: W/System.err(11832):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-06 17:41:50.738: W/System.err(11832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-06 17:41:50.738: W/System.err(11832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-06 17:41:50.738: W/System.err(11832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-06 17:41:50.738: W/System.err(11832):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i had display error mostly getting this errror in soap service nd want solution

Comment: Do you have access to the web service to check if you receive this request? Do you have some SSL behind?

Comment: ya i can access webservice in browser

Comment: Could you provide Namespace and URL?

Comment: ya i had provide it it's working also but most of time it's time out